# Why is my second "scanf" being skipped?

Tags: c, scanf

This is in my main function..

```
    printf("How many marking components in the course? ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfComponents );
    for (int i=0; i<numberOfComponents; i++){

            char c[MAX_STR];
            printf("enter next component name: ");
            fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
            scanf(c, " %c", &c);


            Component comp;

            initComp(&comp, c);
            class.comps[i] = comp;

            }

    printf("How many marking schemes? ");
    scanf(" %d", &numberOfSchemes);
```

I have tried the white space but it still persists

Comment: What is `scanf(c, " %c", &c);` supposed to mean??? What were you trying to do by this `scanf` call?

Answer (score 1):

You should test that your input operations worked; things go haywire when you don't.

This call to `scanf()`:

```
scanf(c, " %c", c);
```

should (as [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) diagnoses in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26416391/15168)) be written differently, but I think it should be more like:

```
char filler;
if (scanf(" %c", &filler) != 1)
    …report problem…
```

The original version uses the line that was just read as the format string, and it is almost certain to fail matching the second input.  If you simply use `scanf(" %c", c)`, which is the simplest edit, then you overwrite the first character of the line of input with the next non-blank character.

There's then the question of why you're making the user enter the extra data after the component name.  They have to enter something.  On the next `fgets()`, the code will read after the first character up to the next newline.  So, if you typed:

```
component-1
component-2
```

The first `fgets()` would read `component-1` and the newline; the `scanf()` as amended would read the `c` of `component-2` into `c[0]`, and then the next `fgets()` would read `omponent-2` plus the newline into `c` on the next iteration.

You could see more of what is going on by adding code to print what you read as you read it:

```
printf("Line 1: [[%s]]\n", c);  // after the fgets()
printf("Line 2: [[%s]]\n", c);  // after the scanf()
```

This is one of the most basic of debugging techniques; echo what you've read to make sure the program got the data you think it got.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing `fgets()` with `scanf()` often causing problems.

`scanf("%d"...` leaves any following white-space like `'\n'` in `stdin` for `fgets()` to get.  The same happens after `scanf(c, " %c", &c);`  (which likely was meant to be `scanf(" %c", c);` or `sscanf(c, " %c", c);`).

```
scanf("%d", &numberOfComponents );
...
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
```

Recommend using only `fgets()` to get user input and use `sscanf()`, `strtol()`, etc. to parse that input.

```
fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
sscanf(c, "%d", &numberOfComponents );

....

fgets(c, sizeof(c), stdin);
// I do not think you need the following line of code.
// Besides it is UB as it attempts to scan and save into the same buffer.
// sscanf(c, "%c", &c );
```

Error checking of the result of `fgets(), sscanf()` omitted, but still good to do.

Comment: by "following line of code" do you mean f gets? or scanf?

Comment: @Nolan Hodge `sscanf(c, "%c", &c );`